# I have to CSS files conflicting - one menu & one gallery - menu does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to combine 2 CSS files for a page with a menu and image gallery.  The gallery works as expected but the menu is frozen. Thanks,
I am using two available scripts from online.  The menu works fine on the other pages however the text in the menu is larger.

```
#roundbar-blue {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#80C8FF url(images/roundbar-blue.gif) 0 25% repeat;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom:0px solid #49A9FF;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#roundbar-blue ul {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li.first {
    border-left:0px solid #49A9FF;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li.last {
    border-right:0px solid #99D8FF;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:.4em 3em;
    color:#ccccff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-left:0px solid #99D8FF;
    border-right:0px solid #49A9FF;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li.active a {
    background:url(images/roundbar-blue.gif) 0 75% repeat;
    color:#ffff00;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li a:hover {
    background:url(images/roundbar-blue.gif) 0 75% repeat;
}
#roundbar-blue ul li a span {
    display:block;
}


/* Slicebox Style */
.sb-slider {
margin: 10px auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

.sb-slider li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: none;
}

.sb-slider li > a {
outline: none;
}

.sb-slider li > a img {
border: none;
}

.sb-slider img {
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.sb-description {
padding: 20px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
background: #CBBFAE;
background: rgba(190,176,155, 0.4);
border-left: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);   
opacity: 0;
color: #fff;

-webkit-transition: all 200ms;
-moz-transition: all 200ms;
-o-transition: all 200ms;
-ms-transition: all 200ms;
transition: all 200ms;
}

.sb-slider li.sb-current .sb-description {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
filter: alpha(opacity=80);  
opacity: 1;
}

.sb-slider li.sb-current .sb-description:hover {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=99)";
filter: alpha(opacity=99);  
background: rgba(190,176,155, 0.7);
}

.sb-perspective {
position: relative;
}

.sb-perspective > div {
position: absolute;

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

-webkit-backface-visibility : hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility : hidden;
-o-backface-visibility : hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility : hidden;
backface-visibility : hidden;
}

.sb-side {
margin: 0;
display: block;
position: absolute;

-moz-backface-visibility : hidden;

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am a noob and dabbler.  Is the parent class a simple fix?

Comment: Issue solved in #wrapper clear:both  needed

Comment: you didn't vote my comment.

Comment: How do I "vote"?  I am new here and I don't see a vote button.